# Necklace Alignment Problem

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

We are given two cyclic $\{0,1\}$ strings $X$ and $Y$ with both length $n$, containing $k$ 0s and $n-k$ 1s. Suppose positions of 1 in $X$ are $x_0,\dots,x_{k-1}$, for $Y$ are $y_0,\dots,y_{k-1}$. We assume $x_0=y_0=0$. Find $c \in \{0,\dots,n-1\}$ and $s \in \{0,\dots,k-1\}$ minimize $$ \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} d(x_i,y_{(i+s) \mod k} +c)^2.$$
Here $d(x,y)=\min(|x-y| \mod n,-|x-y| \mod n)$. Running time in $o(n^2)$.

If the distance function is $$
d'(x,y) = |x-y|,
$$ then we can just expand the sum to obtain $$
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} |x_i-y_{(i+s) \mod k} -c|^2\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_i^2+y_{(i+s) \mod k}^2-2c(x_i-y_{(i+s) \mod k})+c^2-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2x_iy_{(i+s) \mod k}\\
=&\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_i^2+y_{i}^2-2c(x_i-y_{i})+c^2-\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} 2x_iy_{(i+s) \mod k}
\end{aligned}.
$$
The first part is a quadratic function of $c$, which can be solved in $O(n)$,
the second part can be computed like convolution, hence can use FFT to solve in $O(n \log n)$ time.
I wonder if we can transform the original problem to the new problem with $d'$, or is there any other property for original one can be used to solve this?

Comment: I can't seem to find a question here.

Comment: We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question you want answered, in the body of your post.  A question normally ends with "?".  I don't understand what it means to say that positions in $X$ are $x_0,\dots,x_{k-1}$, when the length of $X$ is $n$, not $k$.  Why are indices to $y$ taken modulo $k$ and not $n$?  Is that a typo?  It seems impossible that there is any optimal solution where $|c|>1$.  Do you mean $c \in \{0,1\}$ or $c \in \{-1,0,1\}$?

Comment: What approaches have you already considered, and what progress have you made?  What is the most efficient algorithm you have been able to find so far?  Have you tried applying a Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT)?  Please [edit] your post based on the feedback provided so far, so it contains all relevant information and so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm sorry I missed something in the problem, and I have added more descriptions and my attempts, thanks!